# Odata table not showing odata records

Tags: uitableview, sapui5

I can store odata records but this records not display on my ui table.

**App.controller.js**

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "sap/m/MessageToast",
    "opensap/myapp/model/formatter",
    "opensap/myapp/controller/BaseController",
    "sap/ui/Device"
], function(Controller, MessageToast, formatter, BaseController, Device) {
        "use strict";

        return BaseController.extend("opensap.myapp.controller.App", {
            formatter: formatter,
            onInit: function() {
                // View in temasinin ayarlanmasi
                var oView = this.getView();
                var oComp = this.getOwnerComponent();
                oView.addStyleClass(oComp.getContentDensityClass());
                this.getRouter().attachRoutePatternMatched(this._onRouteMatched, this);

                //View in modelinin ayarlanamsı
                var oViewModel = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel();
                this.getView().setModel(oViewModel);

            },
            _onRouteMatched: function(oEvent) {
            var oController = this;
            var sRouteName = oEvent.getParameter("name");
            var oDataModel = this.getView().getModel();

            this._getAllMasrafs();
            this._getAllMasrafTips();
            },
            _getAllMasrafs: function(oEvent) {
                var oController = this;
                var oDataModel = this.getView().getModel();

                oDataModel.read("/GetMasrafSet", {
                    success: function(resp) {
                        var oMainModel = oController.getView().getModel("mainModel");
                        if (resp.results.length > 0) {
                            oMainModel.setProperty('/MasrafId', resp.results[0].MasrafId);
                            oMainModel.setProperty('/Tarih', resp.results[0].Tarih);
                            oMainModel.setProperty('/ProjeTanımı', resp.results[0].ProjeTanımı);
                            oMainModel.setProperty('/FişNumarası', resp.results[0].FişNumarası);
                            oMainModel.setProperty('/MasrafTipi', resp.results[0].MasrafTipi);
                            oMainModel.setProperty('/Tutar', resp.results[0].Tutar);
                            oMainModel.setProperty('/Para', resp.results[0].Para);
                            oMainModel.setProperty('/Kilometre', resp.results[0].Kilometre);
                            oMainModel.setProperty('/Lokasyon', resp.results[0].Lokasyon);
                            oMainModel.setProperty('/Açıklama', resp.results[0].Açıklama);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(err) {
                    }
                });
            },
            _getAllMasrafTips: function(oEvent) {
                var oController = this;
                var oDataModel = this.getView().getModel();
                var oViewModel = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("app");

                oDataModel.read("/GetMasrafTipiSet", {
                    success: function(resp) {
                        var oMainModel = oViewModel.getData();
                    /*  oMainModel.setProperty("/TAX", resp.results[0].TAX);
                        oMainModel.setProperty("/Taksi", resp.results[0].Taksi); */
                        oMainModel.Masraflar=resp.results;
                        oViewModel.setData(oMainModel);
                    },
                    error: function(err) {

                    }
                });
            },
            getRouter: function() {
                var oComponent = this.getOwnerComponent();
                return oComponent.getRouter();
            },
        });
```

when i press F12 option and debugging, i can see my arrays store in oMainModel but i can not show the records please help me

Where is my mistake?
Thanks
Cansu Koca

Comment: What do you mean you can't show the records? Where do you want to show them? When your OData connection is right, you should get your filled Model back in the success method. If you want to show them in your UI Table and it's not working please provide your view code too.

Comment: Is my solution working?

Comment: No it is not working my post deleted i am new in this place i am sorry i do not know how share my codes. please can you give me an e-mail address for sharing you all codes.. thanks @ThomasL.

Comment: Just edit your question and do it like your App.controller. But why do you fill a JSON Model with the data, why not directly accesing the OData model in your view?

Answer (score 0):

There has to be no "/" in your Table "items" binding:

```
<Panel headerText="Masraf Listesi" expandable="true" expanded="false" >
                <content>
                    <Button press="_onMasrafListesi" text="Click here to see all Masrafs"/>
                    <Table id="idMasrafTable" items="{Masraf>Masraflar}" visibleRowCountMode="Auto">
```